# Tying shoelaces without discomfort

Tags: shoes

People with back problems or large stomachs tend to find it extremely difficult to reach their shoe laces and can be a source of great discomfort.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: This is a workaround rather than a solution: buy shoes with Velcro straps. That will greatly reduce the time it takes to secure them. You could extend your reach to the Velcro with a "grabber" stick that has a sort of lobster claw at the end of it, which you can close and open from the other end.

Comment: @BrettFromLA I think that would qualify as an answer, one which I would upvote, if you were so inclined.

Comment: Thanks @goodguy5. I still don't think it's really an answer, because the question is "How can I fix a problem with the shoes I own" and I'm saying "Just throw them away and buy different shoes". That just doesn't sound like a life hack to me! ;-)

Comment: I read it as "How can I fix this general problem with shoes moving forward in my life", to which "buy shoes that don't have that problem" is a viable answer, but I understand your interpretation. :)

Answer (score 5):

You could replace them with [Elastic Shoe Laces](https://www.google.com/search?q=Elastic%20Shoe%20Laces) - and then the shoes essentially become slip-ons and you can use a shoehorn to get them on without too much bending.

Comment: With some shoes, shoe horns can work even with laced-up standard laces.

Comment: @Lawrence - true, though it depends on how tight you like to tie your shoes.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of bending straight down, try putting your foot up on something about the height of a chair seat.  Then you can tie your shoe from the side.

Answer (score 0):

Tie your shoes when your trousers are not closed tight around your body.
Obviously you will want privacy to do this, like in a room where nobody can look in.

Even without a tight belt or top of trousers bending down is often not the best, sitting down can help, bringing your foot up is mostly better. Find a place you can stand your foot which can take some weight, so it does not break when you bend over to tie and your weight goes on your foot.

While elastic tie and 'tie only once' solutions with normal ties will work for some shoes, many shoes need to be tied tight every time you put on those shoes.
Velco and [cord locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cord_lock) on the shoe laces (strings) will work better for most, but do require investments and learning to handle new (for user) technology. They still require bending over or bringing the foot with shoe up, but for a shorter time.